# Is there a way to highlight element with Watir?

Tags: html, ruby, watir, bots

I keep getting errors doing this:

```
puts browser.table(:after? => span(:text => "Asmeniniai duomenys") )[2][2].text
```

basically saying:

```
undefined method `span' for main:Object (NoMethodError)
```

or

```
undefined method `table' for main:Object (NoMethodError) etc...
```

so I decided that the table was not found. I tried if/else, but it's the first time I used ruby, I did not understand if it worked or not.

So I thought that the simplest way would be to find out how to highlight something.

Could anyone suggest how can I highlight elements or how to fix this problem?

Comment: If you share the html of the page and what you want to do in the table, it would make it easier to suggest how to fix the problem.

Comment: and i found the table using index. Problem solved

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I assume you mean to highlight the element so you can determine if the right element is being found.

You can use the Element#flash method. This method will change the background of the element a couple of times, which should help you figure out what element was found.

For example:

```
browser.table.flash
```